# Как составить такой запрос в PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Необходимо просчитывать на постоянной основе количество входов организаций за определенный интервал времени с 00:00:00 часов по 06:00:00, 6:00:01 по 12:00:00 и тд. Есть 2 таблицы которые соединяются джойном  по ИД1 = ИД2 . в obj_id есть date (timestamptz)"2020-01-01 21:00:00" а в cl_id есть наименование организаций. Кол-во считаем по obj_id. Запрос будет запускаться каждый месяц 1 числа и нужно получить за прошлый месяц информацию. 
как я вижу данную информацию(картинка с низу) есть запрос на кол-во по организаций
    -> как я вижу результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно кол-во входов по организациям или все?

Comment: получается да и чтобы делилось на временные интервалы

Comment: Схему таблиц бы увидеть. В общем случае будет что-то вроде
select org_name, sum(inputs) from ... where ... group by org_id